# find polygon top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left points

Tags: python

I have a set of x,y coordinates representing a contour as follows:

```
array([[[   0,    0]],
       [[   0,    3]],
       [[   1,    3]],
       [[   2,    4]],
       ...,
       [[1189,    5]],
       [[1188,    5]],
       [[1183,    0]]], dtype=int32)
```

How do I find the TYPOLOGICAL top-left,top-right,bottom-right and bottom-left extreme points?

clarification following a comment below: The points sought after are the 'obvious' extreme points / corners of a 4 edges Quadrilateral such as a square, rectangle, chevron or trapezoid. Note that the data is organic and that 2 points which may seem, visibly, on the same horizontal / vertical line may not be, e.g. `(10,60),(9,58)`

I have followed the following logic so far (example for top-left and top-right):

```
# slice k smallest y value elements
l = c[np.argsort(c.reshape(-1,2), axis=0)[:k][:,1]]

#ARBITRARAY - only examinie items whose y value is below 20
l = l[l[:,:,1]<20]

#sort by X value
l = sorted(l, key =lambda x:x[0])
    
minX = l[0][0]
maxX = l[len(l)-1][0]
```

However this rather imperfect and inelegant. Example image attached

[image: smample image]

Comment: You updated your original question to say that you want the "TYPOLOGICAL extreme points". I can not find a definition for that, please provide one. What you call "obvious" is not at all obvious for me : it is unclear how your image relate to the problem, you are making assumptions about point positions (`y<20`) that are not justified in what you explained of the problem, you do not provide example inputs nor outputs, and there may be more relevant tags than just "Python" for your question. Please improve **notably** your question if you seek help, I can't do nothing blinded.

Comment: I think he meant "topological", not "typological". I found [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) which seems appropriate. If the space is a "topological vector space", then the question may make sense. But this is way more a math question than a Python question.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: based on your precisions on this answer's comments, here is the updated version :

```py
import numpy as np


def find_corners(polygon):
    #    topmost,leftmost ───────────►xxxxxxxxxx◄────────── topmost,rightmost
    #                              xxxx         xx
    #    leftmost,topmost ──────►xxx             xx
    #                            x                xx◄────── rightmost,topmost
    #                            x                 x
    # leftmost,bottommost ──────►xx                x
    #                             xx              xx◄────── rightmost,bottommost
    #                              x             xx
    # bottommost,leftmost ────────►xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx◄──────── bottommost,rightmost

    # topmost is minimum Y
    # leftmost is minimum X
    # rightmost is maximum X, or minimum -X
    # bottommost is maximum Y, or minimum -Y
    # X is `pt[0][0]`, Y is `pt[0][1]`

    # going clock-wise :
    topmost_then_rightmost_point =    min(polygon, key=lambda pt: ( pt[0][1], -pt[0][0]))[0]
    rightmost_then_topmost_point =    min(polygon, key=lambda pt: (-pt[0][0],  pt[0][1]))[0]
    rightmost_then_bottommost_point = min(polygon, key=lambda pt: (-pt[0][0], -pt[0][1]))[0]
    bottommost_then_rightmost_point = min(polygon, key=lambda pt: (-pt[0][1], -pt[0][0]))[0]
    bottommost_then_leftmost_point =  min(polygon, key=lambda pt: (-pt[0][1],  pt[0][0]))[0]
    leftmost_then_bottommost_point =  min(polygon, key=lambda pt: ( pt[0][0], -pt[0][1]))[0]
    leftmost_then_topmost_point =     min(polygon, key=lambda pt: ( pt[0][0],  pt[0][1]))[0]
    topmost_then_leftmost_point =     min(polygon, key=lambda pt: ( pt[0][1],  pt[0][0]))[0]

    top_left = topmost_then_leftmost_point
    top_right = topmost_then_rightmost_point
    bottom_right = bottommost_then_rightmost_point
    bottom_left = bottommost_then_leftmost_point

    return tuple(top_left), tuple(top_right), tuple(bottom_right), tuple(bottom_left)


# example from OP :
a = np.array([[[   0,    0]],
              [[   0,    3]],
              [[   1,    3]],
              [[   2,    4]],
              [[1189,    5]],
              [[1188,    5]],
              [[1183,    0]]], dtype=np.int32)
assert find_corners(a) == ((0, 0), (1183, 0), (1189, 5), (1188, 5))


# another example, based on the polygon drawn in the function's comments :
# v---------------------------------------------v
#                x        x
#             x x
#
#           x                xx
#           x
#            x
#             x               x
#                            x
#              x            x
# ^---------------------------------------------^
# using the coordinates you get when putting it in a text editor (starting at line=Y=1, column=X=1) you get clock-wise :
b = np.array(
    [
        [[27, 1]],
        [[30, 4]],
        [[31, 4]],
        [[31, 7]],
        [[30, 8]],
        [[29, 9]],
        [[16, 9]],
        [[15, 7]],
        [[14, 6]],
        [[13, 5]],
        [[13, 4]],
        [[15, 2]],
        [[17, 2]],
        [[18, 1]],
    ], dtype=np.int32)
assert find_corners(b) == ((18, 1), (27, 1), (29, 9), (16, 9))
```

Comment: but then my question would be how to find (for example for the top right corner), min_y for max_x from the given set of coordinates?

Comment: @NoamNaveh I added these details to my answer.

Comment: thanks @lenormju but that's not the intent - this code is for a bbox whilst i'm interested in the explicit polygon corners. for the above example, the function should return something like [(0,0), (900,0), (1189,250), (250,250)]

Comment: @NoamNaveh how do you decide which point is the corner ? If you have two points : `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)`, which one is the corner ?

Comment: ATM, for each point i'm cross referencing between two points. For example, for top-left, i'm concluding the N top most points and then deriving the left most one, then the K left most point and concluding the top most one. This is rather inefficient / inelegant hence my question...

Comment: @NoamNaveh In other words, your top-left corner point is the point satisfying `x=min(all Xs)` and `y=min(Ys of points having X=x)`. Following this definition, I updated my answer to use the correct calculation. I included for each corner the 2 approaches possible, because you did not told me which one to use for the 3 other corners. Your definition is custom, you **SHOULD** have included it in your first question.

Comment: I have added further detail. 
The suggested code is viable as long as, for example referring to the top-left and top-right, p1,p2 share the save y value. if p1 = [18,0] and p2 = [27,1], both top-left and top-right would return p1, would they not?

I have added some more information on my attempt so far

Comment: @NoamNaveh is my updated solution adequate ?

Comment: Useful, thank you.
I've added more information in the answer demonstrating where i think this approach fails

Comment: Stack Overflow notifies me to "avoid extended discussions in comments". Fix your question (as explained in my comment on your question), and maybe I'll try to provide a new solution. End of conversation for this answer.